# Unable to create the where clause for my pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There is a part of table, which I need to modify:

| ID_Subjekt | MutNr | Name | Vornamen | Rufname | RowNr | RowSum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12620 | 30799 | a | NULL | NULL | 1 | 1 |
| 12620 | 41855 | NULL | NULL | b | 1 | 1 |
| 12620 | 55555 | c | NULL | NULL | 1 | 3 |
| 12620 | 55555 | NULL | d | NULL | 2 | 3 |
| 12620 | 55555 | NULL | NULL | e | 3 | 3 |

I need to use something like a vertical coalesce on all name fields with the same `MutNr` and replace the nulls by the existing name. I use a solution with pivot them first, then coalesce:

| ID_Subjekt | MutNr | Name | Vornamen | Rufname | RowNr | RowSum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12620 | 30799 | a | NULL | NULL | 1 | 1 |
| 12620 | 41855 | NULL | NULL | b | 1 | 1 |
| 12620 | 55555 | c | d | e | 1 | 3 |
| 12620 | 55555 | c | d | e | 2 | 3 |
| 12620 | 55555 | c | d | e | 3 | 3 |

My code for get this result looks like follows:

```
update
    dbo.Nametest
Set
    Name = coalesce ("1","2","3")
FROM 
(
    select
        MutNr,
        Name,
        RowNr
    from dbo.Nametest
    where RowSum = 3
) As Temp
PIVOT
(
    Max (Name)
    FOR [RowNr] In([1], [2], [3])
) As pt
where RowSum = 3'
```

I use this code snippet 3 times; once for `Name`, one more for `Vorname` and `Rufname`. The 'where'-clause is actually static for just 1 occurrence of 3 data set. I don't get it fixed to have a solution for the other hundreds of identical `MutNr` too.

Optionally the code should work for different quantities of identical `MutNr` as well, say 2 or 7 identical `MutNr`.

Any help is highly welcome.

Comment: `where RowSum = 3` in  the outer query isn't valid; your subquery (oddly aliased as `temp`) doesn't have a column called `RowSum`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want a window function with `coalesce()`:

```
select ID_Subjekt, MutNr,
       coalesce(name, max(name) over (partition by ID_Subjekt, mutnr)) as name,
       coalesce(Vornamen, max(Vornamen) over (partition by ID_Subjekt, mutnr)) as Vornamen,
       coalesce(Rufname, max(Rufname) over (partition by ID_Subjekt, mutnr)) as Rufname
 from dbo.Nametest;
```

If you want an `update`, you can make this an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select ID_Subjekt, MutNr,
              max(name) over (partition by ID_Subjekt, mutnr) as imputed_name,
              max(Vornamen) over (partition by ID_Subjekt, mutnr) as imputed_Vornamen,
              max(Rufname) over (partition by ID_Subjekt, mutnr) as imputed_Rufname
      from dbo.Nametest
     )
update toupdate
    set name = coalesce(name, imputed_name),
        Vornamen = coalesce(name, imputed_Vornamen),
        Rufname = coalesce(Rufname, imputed_Rufname)
    where name is null or Vornamen is null or Rufname is null;
```

Comment: I thank you so much. Not even that it is working great, it is indeed also way more simpler! Still have to learn a lot!